Angular-ESLint rule exclusion and eslint.config.mjs in Angular project
I'm using ESLint for the first time. I installed it in my Angular project using ng add @angular-eslint/schematics per https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/README.md.
The eslint.config.mjs file created by the installation looked like this:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";


export default [
  {files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts}"]},
  {files: ["**/*.js"], languageOptions: {sourceType: "script"}},
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];

Running ESLint with no adjustment to this configuration, using ng lint, I received the report "628 problems (621 errors, 7 warnings)". Many of these violations are of a couple of rules that aren't of concern to me right now, so I want to turn them off. One of them is prefer-const, so I tried this, based on examples from https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules (in case anyone notices, it's Prettier that's changing double quotes to single quotes on save):
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default [
  { files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts}'], rules: { 'prefer-const': 'off' } },
  { files: ['**/*.js'], languageOptions: { sourceType: 'script' } },
  { languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser } },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];

Running ESLint, I got the same result as the first time. Going further in stages, I wound up in overdrive:
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default [
  { files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts}'], rules: { 'prefer-const': 'off' } },
  { files: ['**/*.js'], languageOptions: { sourceType: 'script' }, rules: { 'prefer-const': 'off' } },
  { rules: { 'prefer-const': 'off' } },
  { languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser } },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  { rules: { 'prefer-const': 'off' } },
];


Still, no change in the outcome. Can anyone see what's wrong?
UPDATE: I pared the config file down to
export default [];

and got the same result. So I have no idea what it's looking at!

The problem turned out to be that even though the eslint.config.mjs file was installed, a .eslintrc.json file, which I thought was supposed to be deprecated, was also installed, and ESLint was using that. I removed it to see if the linter would pick up on the .mjs file but I got an error that way. So I restored .eslintrc.json, added my rule exceptions to that file, and it worked as expected. Shaking my head.

I guess I'm not familiar with the latest ESLint, but my project I'm using ESLint v7 on my Angular project without any specific Angular plugins.
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
  }
}

I just run npm run lint:
"lint": "eslint ./src/app/*.ts ./src/app/**/*.ts",
And it works fine for me.
One alternative would be to litter your project with comments that suppress errors.
